# Вывод окна сообщений от пользователей

Tags: html

Не могу вывести на экран окно сообщений от пользователей. Хочу вывести на левую часть сайта окно сообщений от пользователей, это могут быть пожелания сайту и т.д... или запросы... как это сделать?

Comment: Правильно задайте вопрос: что значит вывести окно сообщений? они у вас уже где то есть? проблема в том, как вывести их из базы, или проблема в том как отобразить их корректно на сайте (html)?

Comment: просто разместить на сайте окно сообщений - это не проблема, она должна работать без ошибок! сообщения, которые должны выводиться, пишет сам посетитель сайта в отдельном окне textarea, а должны выводиться сообщения в отдельном окне снизу(сверху)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по вопросу/комментариям, рановато Вам еще сообщениями от пользователей заниматься...

Для начала советую разобраться с какой-никакой динамической генерацией страниц, хотя-бы предложить пользователю заполнить форму, а потом показать содержимое этой формы в сгенерированной странице.

Потом - браться за тот самый SQL - а точнее, за использование баз данных. Могу порекомендовать книжку, сам с нее начинал php и MySQL - "Build Your Own Database Driven Website Using PHP & MySQL", Kevin Yank, 4-е издание, к сожалению, естественно, на вражеском... 
Можете сразу начинать с этой книги, если знакомы хоть немного с программированием вообще и php в частности...
Удачи!

Comment: если хорошо знаете php, можно обойтись и без базы данных, просто придется записывать полученные комментарии в файл и потом их оттуда читать... (упрощенно)

Comment: спасибо большое! иногда хочешь научиться чему-нибудь новому, так и получается, что никто толком ничего не объяснит... а вы дали хоть какую-то зацепку, мне остается хорошо взяться за эту зацепку! я очень признателен этому сайту, честно! увидел на яндексе(...)страницу эту, программистов, увидел php,html захотелось научиться этому... установил программу dreamweaver, а как работать на нем и как все это связывать даже в руководстве не написано! Спасибо еще раз!)))

Answer (score 0):

А сообщение от куда берется?
Ну вот к примеру можно сделать так

```
<div style="position: fixed; left:5px"> Сообщени </div>
```

Если правильно понял конечно. Если Вы имели виду как вывести скрипт, Вам надо тогда вам к разделу php

Comment: дело в том, что на главной странице должна находиться окно сообщений, примером может служить тот же самый ВКОНТАКТЕ. эта окно, куда пользователь заносит то, что хочет написать, и стена, на которой она должна сохраняться на сайте! в общем случае я понимаю, как это делать(длина строк textarea должна ровняться какой-то переменной, которая и будет служить значению вывода на стену)... я не спец по сайтам, поэтому с ошибками вывода и приравнивания значениям объектов...((

Comment: как я ранее говорил без php или хоть javascript не обойтись. Давайте уточним чтоу Вас есть. Хостинг поддерживает php? Есть лиу него поддержка базы SQL? Если у Вас сайт стоит на вашем компьютере то намного проще все сделать

Comment: у меня есть php! я работаю на dreamweaver cs3. как я уже говорил, я навичок, поэтому с прогой тоже не очень в ладах! мне бы понять, по какому принципу все это работает! а вот что за SQL  я не знаю! это еще одна поддержка Хостинга?

Comment: я работаю на dreamweaver cs3. как я уже говорил, я навичок, поэтому с прогой тоже не очень в ладах!а вот что за SQL я не знаю! это еще одна поддержка Хостинга?

Я сплю или это будущее поколение ПыХаПы? :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope Четко подметил - КрасавчеГ!! ахах)) =) 
Уважаемый, выб хотябы какие нибудь наработки показали нам..

Comment: за последние годы в первый раз себя чувствую лузером! и вам спасибо за помощь!))) это тоже помогает в учебе)))

Comment: Not a looser just a nOOb ;D